# Magmi error: “SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory -”

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

When I try to update pricing for a group of products with an existing .csv in my Magento store Magmi display this error:[image]

How to debug and fix this? There's only one php version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change in your magmi.ini host to the ip

if you runnning these on localhost to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

It says there isn't any (working) mysql.
Does the error show immediately? Or after a while?

Because it could be that mysql crashes when you import the file.
Is the import large?